# Checking if a sentence contains "verb" by nltk?

Tags: python

Sentence: In the forest.
Print: ** Fragment error

```
sents = nltk.sent_tokenize(text)


for sent in sents:
    words = nltk.word_tokenize(sent)
    tagged_words = nltk.pos_tag(words)

    
    for tagged_word in tagged_words:
        curWord = tagged_word[0]
        curPOS = tagged_word[1]
```

Comment: What's your question?  That sentence does not contain a verb. and the output is telling you that.

Comment: "In the forest" is not a sentence.

Answer (score 2):

A solution  would use python primitives `filter` and `any` as follows:

```
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
any_verb =  any(filter(lambda x:"VB" in x[1], nltk.pos_tag(tokens)))
if any_verb:
     # do something
else:
     # do something else
```

First line tokenizes the sentence, then the second line checks if any tag is a verb tag.
You can find a list of the pos tags [here](https://www.guru99.com/pos-tagging-chunking-nltk.html)